# Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to int

Tags: java, loops, addition

Need to write a program to calculate sum of all digits and then give results when the total sum vaue ends with 5 or 8.Please help correct this code!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
        int customerID = in.nextInt();
        while(customerID > 0) 
        {
        int Reminder = customerID % 10;
        int sum = sum+ Reminder;
        customerID = customerID / 10;
        }
        if(sum%5||sum%8)
        {
        System.out.println("Lucky Customer");
        }else
        {
        System.out.println("Unlucky Customer");
        }
        if(sum <0)
        {
        System.out.println("Invalid Input");
        }
        }
        }
```

Comment: That code does not produce that error.

Comment: If it did, you would want to tell us on what line it occurred, what input you provided, what debugging you'd done, and what about the error you didn't understand. (At least.) Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @ Joe, TJ-  truly I got this error on new eclipse workspace that I setup, i will make sure i improve on my clarity in asking a question on this platform.Thanks for the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the fact that this code doesn't produce the error you've mentioned, there are other issues with the code. I've tried to address them instead.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
    int customerID = in.nextInt();
    int sum = 0;
    // sum needs to be initialized outside the while loop
    // or else you wouldn't be able to use it outside it
    while(customerID > 0) {
        int Reminder = customerID % 10;
        sum = sum+ Reminder;
        customerID = customerID / 10;
    }
    if(sum%5 == 0 || sum%8 == 0) {
        //You cannot use int as a condition in if
        System.out.println("Lucky Customer");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Unlucky Customer");
    }
    if(sum <0) {
        System.out.println("Invalid Input");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks yash, for the detailed help on my code. might be a probelm with my eclipse workspace setup, i am still working on it. I made the corrections you mentioned and it helped, Thanks for the detailed input.

Answer (score 2):

instead of doing

```
if(sum%5||sum%8)
    {
    System.out.println("Lucky Customer");
    }
```

> where sum%8 will be true for the value 16 so **you can try this**

```
int rem=sum%10;
if(rem==5||rem==8)
{
      System.out.println("Lucky Customer");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Pooja!! this helped.

Answer (score 1):

This code throws this exception only if your input would contain a dot (e.g.: "3.0"). So either pass the int value (e.g.: "3") or use scanner.nextDouble() and then convert it to int.

Also look into Yash's answer, because your code has other problems too.

+never write variable names with capital letter ("Reminder")!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Please correct your code to remove some compilation errors...

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
        int customerID = in.nextInt();
        int sum = 0;
        while(customerID > 0) {
            int Reminder = customerID % 10;
            sum = sum + Reminder;
            customerID = customerID / 10;   
        }
        if(sum % 5 == 0 || sum % 8 == 0) {
            System.out.println("Lucky Customer");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Unlucky Customer");
        }
        if(sum <0) {
            System.out.println("Invalid Input");
        }
    }
}
```